# How to make a string connection on web.config for a SQL Server Connection?

Tags: asp.net

I'm creating a Site for ASP.NET, actually I made a EF model to create my DataBase, but this is just creating a SQL Express .mdf DB, I would like to know how I should change the Connection String to connect to an SQL Server DB.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WingtipToys;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="WingtipToys" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\wingtiptoys.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Comment: it's an example of the connection string construction to connect to an SQL database.  Change the names where appropriate.

Comment: Do you mind adding the explanation to your answer text so that the people unfamiliar with the matter understand it better?

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory but, substitute ServerName for the actual server name where your SQL Server instance is running; DatabaseName becomes the database with that MSSQL instance you wish to connect with; userid becomes the actual user ID you use to connect; and password becomes the actual password for that user ID.  MultipleActiveResultSets is not necessary.

Comment: Dean, StackOverflow encourages writing full answers to questions, comments are a second-class citizen. It would be helpful if you put the information from your last comment to the answer body.